# Subreport shows in Designer but not in document Viewer [DevExpress]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, devexpress

I have created a Master-Detail Report using subreports that are populated via stored procedures. I'm passing main report as Url in document viewer to bind the method. Everything is fine when we preview but only main report shows on run time.
I have no idea why it's not working. when we preview the main report it shows the main report data and sub report data which inserted in main report as group footer. but when we run the app it only shows Main report data. sub report doesn't show at all.I also checked the error on browser console.And it's fine.
Both main report and sub report has data source and we have to give two parameters to show data which shows in preview.
please help me what's the problem ..
I've posted the code of three classes.

Report Storage WEb Extension Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CheckReport
{
    public class ReportStorageWebExtension : DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.Extensions.ReportStorageWebExtension
    {
        readonly string reportDirectory;
        const string FileExtension = ".repx";
        public ReportStorageWebExtension(string reportDirectory)
        {
            this.reportDirectory = reportDirectory;
        }
        public override bool CanSetData(string url)
        {
            // Determines whether or not it is possible to store a report by a given URL. 
            // For instance, make the CanSetData method return false for reports that should be read-only in your storage. 
            // This method is called only for valid URLs (i.e., if the IsValidUrl method returned true) before the SetData method is called.
            return true;
        }
        public override bool IsValidUrl(string url)
        {
            // Determines whether or not the URL passed to the current Report Storage is valid. 
            // For instance, implement your own logic to prohibit URLs that contain white spaces or some other special characters. 
            // This method is called before the CanSetData and GetData methods.
            return true;
        }
        public override byte[] GetData(string url)
        {
            // Returns report layout data stored in a Report Storage using the specified URL. 
            // This method is called only for valid URLs after the IsValidUrl method is called.
            try
            {
                return File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(reportDirectory, url + FileExtension));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException(new FaultReason(string.Format("Could not find report '{0}'.", url)), new FaultCode("Server"), "GetData");
            }
        }
        public override Dictionary<string, string> GetUrls()
        {
            // Returns a dictionary of the existing report URLs and display names. 
            // This method is called when running the Report Designer, 
            // before the Open Report and Save Report dialogs are shown and after a new report is saved to a storage.
            return Directory.GetFiles(reportDirectory, "*" + FileExtension)
                                     .Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension)
                                     .ToDictionary<string, string>(x => x);
        }
        public override void SetData(XtraReport report, string url)
        {
            // Stores the specified report to a Report Storage using the specified URL. 
            // This method is called only after the IsValidUrl and CanSetData methods are called.
            report.SaveLayoutToXml(Path.Combine(reportDirectory, url + FileExtension));
        }
        public override string SetNewData(XtraReport report, string defaultUrl)
        {
            // Stores the specified report using a new URL. 
            // The IsValidUrl and CanSetData methods are never called before this method. 
            // You can validate and correct the specified URL directly in the SetNewData method implementation 
            // and return the resulting URL used to save a report in your storage.
            SetData(report, defaultUrl);
            return defaultUrl;
        }
    }
}
```

Viewer

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Report";
}

<h2>Report</h2>

@using DevExpress.AspNetCore
@model DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport
<link href="~/node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/node_modules/@@devexpress/analytics-core/dist/css/dx-analytics.common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/node_modules/@@devexpress/analytics-core/dist/css/dx-analytics.light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/node_modules/devexpress-reporting/dist/css/dx-webdocumentviewer.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- 3rd-party dependencies -->
<script src="~/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/knockout/build/output/knockout-latest.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/cldrjs/dist/cldr.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/cldrjs/dist/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/cldrjs/dist/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/cldrjs/dist/cldr/unresolved.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize/message.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize/currency.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize/date.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/devextreme/dist/js/dx.all.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/@@devexpress/analytics-core/dist/js/dx-analytics-core.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/devexpress-reporting/dist/js/dx-webdocumentviewer.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("body").addClass("sidebar-xs");
    });
</script>
<input type="hidden" class="reportType" value="@ViewBag.reportType">
<input type="hidden" class="reportName" value="@ViewBag.ReportName">
<input type="hidden" class="reportType" value="NonParametrize">
@if (ViewBag.reportType == "Parametriz")
{
    <style type="text/css">
        .dxrd-preview .dxrd-right-panel-collapse, .dxrd-preview .dxrd-right-panel, .dxrd-preview .dxrd-right-tabs {
            display: none;
        }

        .dxrd-designer-wrapper .dx-shadow.dxrd-tab-panel-right {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    @Html.DevExpress().WebDocumentViewer("DocumentViewer").Height("1000px").Bind(Model);
}
else
{
    @Html.DevExpress().WebDocumentViewer("DocumentViewer").Height("1000px").Bind(ViewBag.ReportName);
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DevExpress.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

namespace CheckReport
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddDevExpressControls();
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "node_modules")),
                RequestPath = "/node_modules"
            });
            var reportDirectory = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Report");
            DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.Extensions.ReportStorageWebExtension.RegisterExtensionGlobal(new ReportStorageWebExtension(reportDirectory));
            DevExpress.XtraReports.Configuration.Settings.Default.UserDesignerOptions.DataBindingMode = DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.DataBindingMode.Expressions;
            app.UseDevExpressControls();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution and it was surprisingly just one line of code.
When I pass the main report by its URL to the Web Document Viewer's Bind method, it looks for a report in the custom report storage. So if I want to work with a custom report storage and pass a main report by its URL, then I have to use the XRSubreport.ReportSourceURL property to specify a URL of a report definition file from a report storage.
But the easiest way which i preferred more was to work in the Visual Studio Report Designer and assign a subreport class instance to the XRSubreport.ReportSource property, then pass a main report instance to my Web Document Viewer's Bind(XtraReport) method:

```
@Html.DevExpress().WebDocumentViewer("DocumentViewer").Height("1000px").Bind(new aspNetCoreReportingApp.Reports.DSR_Khudian());
```

So all i had to do is to add an instance of main report in Bind Method.